# Add custom names to AllowedValues

Tags: json

I have the following section of my JSON template file.

```
"environment": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "Test",
  "allowedValues": [
    "Development",
    "Test",
    "User Acceptance Testing",
    "Load Testing",
    "Stage",
    "Production"
  ]
```

When run, this will display this list of environments as is. However, I want to be able to use what you see here is display names only, then once one is selected, another value is applied, e.g. Production = PDN, Load Testing = LT.

How would I write this into the above code?

Comment: Which code?? Javascript or something? What did you tried? Please give more information!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using default json-schema? Because there are no keywords such as `defaultValue` and `allowedValues` in it.

See http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html for details.

First of all, for your purposes you should use `enum` instead of `allowedValues` and `default` instead of `defaultValue`, so you schema will look like:

```
"environment": {
  "type": "string",
  "default": "Test",
  "enum": [
    "Development",
    "Test",
    "User Acceptance Testing",
    "Load Testing",
    "Stage",
    "Production"
  ]
}
```

And for you question, i guess that this kind of processing should be implemented in your JavaScript(*or what are you using*) code, which uses your json-schema.

So you should store your "short" versions of `environment` (like PND, LT, etc.) into schema and your full values into your code. May be in localization part of your program.

Final version of your schema:

```
"environment": {
  "type": "string",
  "default": "TST",
  "enum": [
    "DMT",
    "TST",
    "UAT",
    "LT",
    "STG",
    "PND"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Don't think so, Azure uses normal JSON, I can edit it in visual studio, and it gets validated first.

Comment: @MarcKean, oh. Now i got it. Please provide information about your framework in the qiestion details, because it's not obvious, that you are using Azure and its field scheme.